# Can the Macbook's webcam be ON without LED indication?

Tags: safari, security, camera, webcam, privacy

Was reading some topics online about hackers accessing user's webcams (on Windows) to spy on them etc, and I am now interested to know if I'm at any risk.

To make it simple, these are my questions :

- Can Safari allow websites to activate the webcam without my permission ?
- Can the webcam be activated without the LED being lit ?
- Are there any known trojans that affect macs and leave them vulnerable for such hacks ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that this would be possible. [Here](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/141508/Is+the+iSight+indicator+LED+hardwired+or+can+it+be+circumvented) is also a very recent question similiar to yours from the ifixit.com forums. Regarding your questions: I tend to say no to them all.

Comment: I was going to post the same link on iFixit that has several good answers.

Answer (score 4):

[This research](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/36569/camera.pdf?sequence=1) paper reported by the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2013/12/18/research-shows-how-macbook-webcams-can-spy-on-their-users-without-warning/) and [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/12/perv-utopia-light-on-macbook-webcams-can-be-bypassed/) says yes.

Though it was only tested on "old" Macs (Late PPC, early Intel)

Answer (score 0):

> Can Safari allow websites to activate the webcam without my permission
>   ?

Don't worry about Safari enabling your webcam. The browser would have to use something like flash/plugin to request access.  You would be more susceptible to rogue installed apps for accessing the webcam.

I believe Apple's own [find my device](http://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html) can take photos of the user (if it is stolen). I recall seeing news about people taking photos of their thieves and reporting it to police.

Answer (score -2):

Any software that so chooses may ask you to initiate a FaceTime session. It cannot start one without your say-so.

The FaceTime cameras (like yours) cannot be active without the LCD on.

There aren't really any hacks that matter.

There are a number of really lame, goofy hacks in some web plugins (Flash), that could be used to access a Flash player that displays your camera's stream, for example, but you'd have to have the camera on, or accept a FaceTime session, or whatever.

Comment: This is the corporate political answer, isn't it? Or am I totally wrong and this is the result of an analysis of the set of library interfaces to turn the camera on and to turn the green LED on?
Please clarify.